# mariadb is not running after restart Openstack train

Tags: mariadb, openstack, podman

I have a OpenStack train deployment with a single controller node. disk went full I deleted the cinder-volumes loop file after reboot nothing is working because all the services are unable to connect with mysql db.
2021-12-21 16:41:54.345 27 WARNING oslo_db.sqlalchemy.engines [req-c3a82c9d-d6be-42cd-b54a-a1258171c777 - - - - -] SQL connection failed. -709 attempts left.: oslo_db.exception.DBConnectionError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')

i checked the mariadb container its giving me this error:
()[mysql@overcloud-controller-0 /]$ mysql
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111)

in podman container logs for mariadb i am getting this:

- sudo -E kolla_set_configs
  INFO:**main**:Loading config file at /var/lib/kolla/config_files/config.json
  INFO:**main**:Validating config file
  INFO:**main**:Kolla config strategy set to: COPY_ALWAYS
  INFO:**main**:Copying service configuration files
  INFO:**main**:Deleting /etc/sysconfig/clustercheck
  INFO:**main**:Copying /var/lib/kolla/config_files/src/etc/sysconfig/clustercheck to /etc/sysconfig/clustercheck
  INFO:**main**:Deleting /etc/xinetd.d/galera-monitor
  INFO:**main**:Copying /var/lib/kolla/config_files/src/etc/xinetd.d/galera-monitor to /etc/xinetd.d/galera-monitor
  INFO:**main**:Deleting /etc/xinetd.conf
  INFO:**main**:Copying /var/lib/kolla/config_files/src/etc/xinetd.conf to /etc/xinetd.conf
  INFO:**main**:Writing out command to execute
  ++ cat /run_command
- CMD='/usr/sbin/xinetd -dontfork'
- ARGS=
- sudo kolla_copy_cacerts
- [[ ! -n '' ]]
- . kolla_extend_start
  ++ : /var/log/kolla/mariadb
  ++ [[ ! -d /var/log/kolla/mariadb ]]
  +++ stat -c %a /var/log/kolla/mariadb
  ++ [[ 2755 != \7\5\5 ]]
  ++ chmod 755 /var/log/kolla/mariadb
  ++ [[ -n '' ]]
  ++ [[ -n '' ]]
  ++ [[ -n '' ]]
- echo 'Running command: '''/usr/sbin/xinetd -dontfork''''
  Running command: '/usr/sbin/xinetd -dontfork'
- exec /usr/sbin/xinetd -dontfork

looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: The information provided doesn't show the state of your MariaDB.